# i need to get the context from my main Activity inside my view class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created a View class and i need the context from my mainActivity to create my mp3 player. I dont have nothing on my mainActivity, i'm doing everything on my View Class. Example of what i want to do:

```
    if(player == null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.onepieceost);
    }
```

But this code doesnt work, cause "this" cant take the context from my main activity. I want to know how i can take this context.

Comment: it will be helpfull if you put the code of your mainactivity and view class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `void function` and call this from your `MainActivity` like this:

```
public void player(Context context){

if(player == null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.onepieceost);
    }
   if(player != null || !player.isPlaying()){
        player.start();
    }else {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.prepare();
            player.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //null
        }
    }
}
```

And call this function from your `MainActivity` like this:
`player(this);`

OR

You could create a `public constructor` in your `View class` and pass `context` from `MainActivity` to your `View` class like this:

```
public class myview{

Context myContext;

public myview(Context context){
myContext = context;
}
//your methods
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would also try to make your View class a subclass of MainActivity:)